# Rails passenger /tmp/ folder permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

Afternoon all,

Attempting to get my Rails app working on a Mac Apache MySql Ruby setup and a passenger directory. When I try and access it through the web front eend I get the following error.

```
*** Exception Errno::EACCES in spawn manager (Permission denied - /tmp/passenger.1.0.54375/generation-0/spawn-server/socket.54643.70317578161560) (process 54643, thread #<Thread:0x007fe82c0519c0>):
```

Apache config for this vhost looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName test.me
  DocumentRoot /Users/me/Projects/app/public
  <Directory /Users/me/Projects/app/public>
     AllowOverride all
     Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
```

Can anyone see what I am missing? FWIW the folder it tries to access is owned by root which seems a bit odd

```
drwsr-xr-x   3 root        wheel   102 11 Oct 15:25 passenger.1.0.54375
```

Comment: If this is just for development the easiest route to take might be.. cd to the project directory in terminal and do `passenger start`

Comment: This could also help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055575/rails-application-needs-access-to-a-tmp-directory if you don't want to use `passenger start`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passenger assumes the owner of `config/environement.rb` (see http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Security%20of%20user%20switching%20support.html, restart apache/passenger for changes to take effect) and this user needs write and execute rights for `tmp`.

So, find out who owns `config/environement.rb`:

```
$> ls -lah config/environment.rb 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 152 Jan 22 07:53 config/environment.rb
```

I choose www-data here, as this is the user my apache uses. I don't reccomend root.

```
$> chown www-data:www-data config/environment.rb
```

Giving this user full access to the `tmp` folder and its contents should be sufficient:

```
$> chmod -R 700 tmp
```